# uninitialized constant Mongoid::Spacial::Document::ClassMethods::Mongo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

I am trying to use `mongoid_spacial` gem and here is how my model looks:

```
class Place
    include Mongoid::Document
    include Mongoid::Spacial::Document

        field :name, :type => String

        field :source,            type: Array,    spacial: true
        field :mouth,             type: Array,    spacial: {lat: :latitude, lng: :longitude,    return_array: true }

       spacial_index :source

      end
```

The error is

```
   uninitialized constant Mongoid::Spacial::Document::ClassMethods::Mongo
   MONGOID: Attempted to constantize Property, trying without namespacing.
   MONGOID: Failed to determine model from app/models/property.rb:
   NameError:uninitialized constant Mongoid::Spacial::Document::ClassMethods::Mongo`
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to `mongoid_spacial` 0.2.17, which fixes [a namespacing bug you're seeing](https://github.com/ryanong/mongoid_spacial/issues/31).